# What wire is required to run 300' to a 50 amp RV plug?

Tags: electrical

I have to run approximately 300 feet from the breaker to the outlet, what size wire will I need?

My RV has 2 ac units that do run during the summer here in Texas!

Comment: Shop before picking a size. Common thing that does not appear "logical" but apparently is due to volume of production or some such economics is for 2-2-2-4 aluminum "mobile home feeder" that will do 90A (or have lower voltage drop for a long 50A) is actually less expensive than smaller size wires. So check what's available for how much in your local area before settling on somethting "just big enough" that might cost more. And consider an "RV Subpanel" that would let you have a couple of 20A 120V circuits separate from the 50A 240V one on wire that size...

Comment: 50 amps normally require 6 gauge wire.  For 300 feet will need to upgrade to 4 or even 2 gauge wire.

Answer (score 6):

### 2-2-2-4 aluminum is *made for this*

like Ecnerwal says.   Well, not this *exactly*; it's made for 100A main feeder for mobile homes. But it fits hand to glove for the application - underground feeder going to a remote site.  It enjoys "economies of scale" because of its popularity.

But when you calculate the voltage drop for your application, it fits perfect at 2.97% voltage drop at 40A draw (far more than you'll use most of the time; think "both A/Cs *and the dryer* running). And at about 1/3 the cost of copper.  Presuming that your A/C units are wired into opposite phases on the RV panel, this will work very well.  Have your RV mechanic make sure they are balanced thusly.

If they are wired onto the same phase, that's "the hard way to do it" and you would need much larger wire.

Presumably you'll bring it to an "RV stand" panel which typically has a 50A RV outlet and 20A GFCI, or alternately also a 30A RV outlet.

There is nothing wrong with aluminum at these large sizes; they are proven reliable. All connections of this size are properly rated for aluminum wire, and torqued to spec.  These are the keys to success. Most panel lugs are not only aluminum rated, they are *made of* aluminum.

Answer (score -1):

Size of wire you need to run approximately 300 feet to breaker box will depend on the amperages requirements of your RV's 2 A/C unit and voltage of your electricals.

Assuming a standard RV electrical system with a 120VAC/60Hz supply and typical AC unit amperages, you will likely need a wiring size of at least 2 AWG  for a 100-amp circulation or draught.

Not so sure about voltage drop, temperature and other electrical loads though

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).